# Schema mismatch for feature column in multivariate time series ML.NET

Tags: time-series, forecasting, ml.net

I want to create a model to predict time series. I present my case in case someone can help me.

I have an entity where I store data that is related in time series like in the image (time). I want to train a model based on multivariate time series to be able to predict the next record given a time series, with less length than my saved data (TestData).

The column to predict depends directly on the "Features" columns.

[Example of data and objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkACo.png)

I've created code similar to this to train my model, but I'm getting an error when trying to convert my multivariate string to univariate.

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

// Load the data
List<TimeSerie> data = LoadData(mlContext);
IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

// Converting multivariate to univariate
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms
.Concatenate("Features", nameof(TimeSerie.Feature1),
                         nameof(TimeSerie.Feature2),
                         nameof(TimeSerie.Feature3));
// nameof(TimeSerie.ColumnToPredict));I have a doubt if I should include my column to predict or not

// Define the training pipeline
IEstimator<ITransformer> forecastEstimator =dataProcessPipeline
.Append(mlContext.Forecasting
      .ForecastBySsa(outputColumnName: nameof(PredictionSerie.ForecastedTotal),
            inputColumnName: "Features",
            windowSize: 4,
            seriesLength: data.Count(),
            trainSize: data.Count(),
            horizon: 1,
            confidenceLevel: 0.95f,
            confidenceLowerBoundColumn: nameof(PredictionSerie.ConfidenceLowerBound),
            confidenceUpperBoundColumn:  nameof(PredictionSerie.ConfidenceUpperBound))
 );
         
// Fit the model to the training data
ITransformer forecastTransformer = forecastEstimator.Fit(dataView);

// Create the forecast engine used for creating predictions.
TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<TimeSerie, PredictionSerie> forecastEngine = 
                forecastTransformer.CreateTimeSeriesEngine<TimeSerie, PredictionSerie>(mlContext); 

IEnumerable<TimeSeriesPrediction> predictions = forecastEngine.Predict(trainingData);
```

My classes are

```
 public class TimeSerie
    {
        public float Time { get; set; }
        public float Feature1 { get; set; }
        public float Feature2 { get; set; }
        public float Feature3 { get; set; }
        public float ColumnToPredict { get; set; }
    }

    public class PredictionSerie
    {
        public float[] ForecastedTotal { get; set; }

        public float[] ConfidenceLowerBound { get; set; }

        public float[] ConfidenceUpperBound { get; set; }
    }
```

With this code when executing the training (Fit) I get the following error "'Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected Single, got Vector<Single, 3> Arg_ParamName_Name"

I tried changing the schema of my input data by:

```
 public class TimeSerie
    {
        public float Time { get; set; }
        public float[] Feature { get; set; }
    }
```

and load my Features columns inside this field, but it still throws me the error.

At the moment of predicting the results I have the doubt of how to pass my result because I have to pass a record list to predict the next one, but in a test that I did this did not go well:

```
.CreateTimeSeriesEngine< List<TimeSeries>, PredictionSeries>
```

I'm new to this area, any corrections to my code or method suggestions to fix this kind of problem would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)